# C# Permutate a set of strings given n and given the maximum array length

Tags: c#, arrays, permutation

How can you permutate the set of strings based on the set length, I have lets say 50 values in an array and only want to combine 24 values that is comma delimited Examples: (string1,string2,string3) but without ever repeating the combinations and the order. I have this code below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var values1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        //foreach (var permutation in values1.GetPermutations())
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", permutation));
        //}

        var values2 = new[] { "asd", "das", "sad", "q1we", "asd" };

        foreach (var permutation in values2.GetPermutations())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", permutation));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class SomeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        var array = enumerable as T[] ?? enumerable.ToArray();

        var factorials = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length + 1)
            .Select(Factorial)
            .ToArray();

        for (var i = 0L; i < factorials[array.Length]; i++)
        {
            var sequence = GenerateSequence(i, array.Length - 1, factorials);

            yield return GeneratePermutation(array, sequence);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> GeneratePermutation<T>(T[] array, IReadOnlyList<int> sequence)
    {
        var clone = (T[])array.Clone();

        for (int i = 0; i < clone.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Swap(ref clone[i], ref clone[i + sequence[i]]);
        }

        return clone;
    }

    private static int[] GenerateSequence(long number, int size, IReadOnlyList<long> factorials)
    {
        var sequence = new int[size];

        for (var j = 0; j < sequence.Length; j++)
        {
            var facto = factorials[sequence.Length - j];

            sequence[j] = (int)(number / facto);
            number = (int)(number % facto);
        }

        return sequence;
    }

    static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
    {
        T temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    private static long Factorial(int n)
    {
        long result = n;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            result = result * i;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

How can I be able to combine an array of string (24 values) into 100 rows of unique combination? Can you please explain how and whats the best way on how to do it?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Combinatorics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I would do it like this

```
public static class StringPermutator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class to permutate input values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputValues">An array of inputs to be permutated</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfResults">The number of outputs we want to have</param>
    /// <param name="maxValuesPerRow">The number of values to be combined in each output row</param>
    /// <returns>An IEnumerable of unique permutated string ouptuts</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> Permutate<T>(T[] inputValues, int numberOfResults, int maxValuesPerRow)
    {
        HashSet<string> output = new HashSet<string>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        //Loop until we have the number of results we want
        while (output.Count < numberOfResults)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            HashSet<int> usedIndexes = new HashSet<int>();

            //Loop until we have the right number of values in a single row
            while (usedIndexes.Count < maxValuesPerRow)
            {
                int index = rnd.Next(inputValues.Length);
                //Ensure that each index we use is unique and only used once per row
                if (usedIndexes.Add(index))
                    sb.Append(inputValues[index].ToString()).Append(",");
            }

            sb.Length--;    //remove the last comma
            output.Add(sb.ToString());   //value is only added if unique
        }

        return output.ToList();
    }
}
```

You can call it like this

```
var result = StringPermutator.Permutate(stringValues, 100, 24);

foreach (var permutation in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", permutation));
}
```

Basically the class uses HashSet which ensures that only unique values can be entered, therefore we can be sure that our output is not duplicated and we just loop until we have the right number of generated output values.

Within this loop then we randomly pick an index to use, and to ensure that this is also unique for each output value then we again use a HashSet to store the indexes used and loop until we have combined the right number of values into a single output row.

The return is an Enumerable list.
This should work on any type of input value, not just strings.

Edit:

Just to clarify, as per the comments.
If you don't have enough inputs to generate the number of permutations and rows combinations that you need then you could get stuck in a loop.  So you should code a method to break out of this but in order to keep the example simple I didn't do that.

Comment: Won't your code go into an infinite loop if the caller miscalculates the number of possible results on the high side since the outer while loop will never be satisfied?

Comment: What guarantees do you have that the inner loop that generates "permutations" will generate all the sequences needed even if the caller correctly calculated the correct number of results?

Comment: @Ants Yes, you must ensure that you have enough values so that would not happen.  But I wanted to keep the code simple, so hence did not have a breakout mechanism (But I will add a comment to clarify this).

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith how can you add a blank value in the middle of the index example at index 13 of a maximum value of 24?

Answer (score 2):

I propose the use of more deterministic permutation generator. Couple this with existing LINQ extension methods like `Select()`, `Distinct()` and `Take()` and you've got what you need:

```
var results = values2.Permutations(24)
                     .Select(p => String.Join(",", p))
                     .Distinct()
                     .Take(100);
foreach (var permutation in results)
    Console.WriteLine(permutation);
```

where `Permutations()` is implemented as an extension method. The number 24 here indicates how many items should be in each permutation. It is the `k` in <sub>n</sub>P<sub>k</sub>.

The `Select()` call creates a string string with all the items for the particular permutation.

The `Distinct()` call makes sure that we only end up with unique strings.

The `Take()` call limits the number of strings that we collect.

Here is a naive implementation using recursion to generate the permutations:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Permutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int k)
{
    if (k < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(k), "May not be negative");

    var items = source.ToArray();
    if (k > items.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(k), "May not be bigger than the number of items in source");

    var buffer = new ArraySegment<T>(items, 0, k);
    return Permute(0);

    IEnumerable<T[]> Permute(int depth)
    {
        if (depth == k)
        {
            yield return buffer.ToArray();
            yield break;
        }

        for (int i = depth; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            Swap(depth, i);
            foreach (var permutation in Permute(depth + 1))
                yield return permutation;
            Swap(depth, i);
        }
    }

    void Swap(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a != b)
        {
            T t = items[a];
            items[a] = items[b];
            items[b] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

I leave it to you to replace the implementation with the algorithm of your choice.